# How to parse markdown's yaml frontmatter inside jsx file/ React Component?

Tags: reactjs, markdown

I'm trying to get all files within a folder which contains markdown files. So what I want to do is get all MD files from this folder and then for each, I want to parse the YAML frontmatter and convert to object. This must be done inside my JSX file.

I've tried parsing it in a nodejs file, and then importing it in my jsx file. Unfortunately I was having errors with it. So, how do you think can this be done?